# ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expiredConnection .even after commit also getting same issue

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

```
Query : "SELECT * FROM basictasks WHERE STATUS = 1 and rownum = 1 order by TASKID for update nowait" 

octTransaction.Commit();
octTransaction.Dispose();
```

```
 Tasks tasks = new Tasks();
               DataLayer datalayer = new DataLayer();
               datalayer = Login.objDataLayer;
               OracleCommand ocdSelect = new OracleCommand();
               datalayer.BeginTransaction();
               Sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM basictasks WHERE STATUS = 1 and rownum = 1 order by TASKID for update nowait ";
               ocdSelect.CommandText = Sqlquery;

               DataTable dt = datalayer.GetResultDT(ocdSelect, false);
               if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
               {
                   tasks.TaskID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["TASKID"]);
                   tasks.MechineName = dt.Rows[0]["MACHINENAME"].ToString();
                   tasks.Parameters = dt.Rows[0]["PARAMETERS"].ToString();
                   tasks.TaskName = dt.Rows[0]["TASKNAME"].ToString();
                   tasks.Description = dt.Rows[0]["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();
                   tasks.Status = 2;
                   tasks.StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
                   tasks.FinishJob = false;
                   Sqlquery = "UPDATE basictasks SET STATUS = " + tasks.Status + ", STARTTIME = SYSDATE,MACHINENAME = '" + Common.MechineName + "',REMARK = ' ',ENDTIME = null WHERE TASKID = " + tasks.TaskID + "";
                   datalayer.TableOperation_BySQL(Sqlquery, true);
                   if (datalayer != null)
                       datalayer.CheckTransaction(true);
                   return tasks;
               }

               else
               {
                   if (datalayer != null)
                       datalayer.CheckTransaction(true);
               }
           }
```

once close connection and reopen the connection then working. but I don't want it to open and close connection every time. I want to use one connection.

Comment: Why do you use `FOR UPDATE` clause? Are you actually updating anything returned by this `select` statement? If not, remove that clause and you'll be OK.

Comment: @Littlefoot  Yes I am updating return by select result.

Comment: Is taskid  a PK in the table?

Comment: @gsalem Yes primary key.

Comment: Is there any kind of multithreading going on in your code? I'm asking because a single session should not get this kind of error. I've got no experience at all with c#, so can't tell.

Comment: @gsalem Yes correct I am using multithreading. I solved the issue  using (alter session set ddl_lock_timeout = 600;) query executed in database.but facing multible connections session issue .i am trying to solve that problem.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do with this multi-threaded code, you can try adding 'skip locked' after the 'for update'. This will make each thread take the next non-locked row and work on it. Should let you avoid the issue. This is just a guess, as you did not explain what you're trying to do.